# Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. using Selenium3

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium3

```
Browser: Firefox 50 version
Selenium Jar files : 3.0.1 jar
OS: Windows 7 enterprise 64 bit
```

While executing the scripts by right clicking on the xml file "Run as testNG suite" the browser opens but immediately the error is displayed in the console.

Can any one please guide me do i need to downgrade the browser if so what would be the supporting version for selenium 3 version.

Error Log:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\raghuveer.amajala\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse-1646049448\testng-customsuite.xml

org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
true,"v":"1.0","st":1478328645000}},"winreg-app-user":{"ocplugin@webex.com":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WebEx\\Productivity Tools","e":false,"v":"2.0","st":1485264359732,"mt":1463471846535}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","e":true,"v":"50.0","st":1478328645000}},"winreg-app-global":{"{D19CA586-DD6C-4a0a-96F8-14644F340D60}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\McAfee\\SystemCore","e":false,"v":"15.4.0","st":1477288713580,"mt":1476678768866}}}
1485322859314   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
1485322859325   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
1485322859326   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\aushelper@mozilla.org.xpi
1485322859331   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on aushelper@mozilla.org version 1.0
1485322859333   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1485322859334   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi
1485322859343   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on e10srollout@mozilla.org version 1.5
1485322859344   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1485322859345   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi
1485322859349   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on firefox@getpocket.com version 1.0.5
1485322859360   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Starting async load of XPI database C:\Users\RAGHUV~1.AMA\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous8881786919455687854webdriver-profile\extensions.json
1485322859362   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Registering manifest for C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1485322859362   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loading bootstrap scope from C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\features\webcompat@mozilla.org.xpi
1485322859365   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Calling bootstrap method startup on webcompat@mozilla.org version 1.0
1485322859367   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
1485322859367   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: XPIProvider
1485322859367   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: LightweightThemeManager
1485322859367   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
1485322859368   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: LightweightThemeManager
1485322859368   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: GMPProvider
1485322859386   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
1485322859386   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: GMPProvider
1485322859386   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PluginProvider
1485322859387   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
1485322859387   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PluginProvider
1485322859387   addons.manager  DEBUG   Completed startup sequence
1485322859726   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Async JSON file read took 0 MS
1485322859726   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Finished async read of XPI database, parsing...
1485322859728   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   Successfully read XPI database
1485322859739   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: <unnamed-provider>
1485322859739   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
1485322859740   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: <unnamed-provider>
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
1485322859848   addons.manager  DEBUG   Starting provider: PreviousExperimentProvider
1485322859849   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PreviousExperimentProvider
1485322859849   addons.manager  DEBUG   Provider finished startup: PreviousExperimentProvider

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
    at Registration.Registration_webdriver.SetUp(Registration_webdriver.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:175)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:107)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)`
```

Below is the `setup()` method this is my before class.

```
@BeforeClass
public void SetUp()throws Exception
{ 
 //System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","D:\\jar-files\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.39.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
 //driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    //String firefoxlocation=System.getenv("ProgramFiles(X86)")+"\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe";
    //System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", firefoxlocation);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverPath+"geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get(partnerportalurl);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    String title=driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println(title);

}
```

Comment: did you download geckodriver.exe and add to system PATH, which is default standard to automate Firefox since Selenium 3.0?

Comment: Thanks Naveen . Yes i did download the geckodriver.exe and added to the system path

Comment: please share the sample code, testng.xml, error log.

Comment: Hi Naveen please look at the errror log

Comment: plz share code for `setup` method, error is at  `Registration_webdriver.SetUp(Registration_webdriver.java:88)`. also, share the relevant code where you are giving System path for `geckodriver.exe` file.

Comment: Thanks Naveen for a quick reply please find the below code.

Comment: Hi naveen i have edited my question and added the setup method there and i am declaring the string driverPath in the main class.

Comment: I don't see any issue in the code (if driver path evaluated to `geckodriver.exe` file path correctly. just check compatibility of firefox and geckodriver in terms of versions and bit version (32 or 64).

Comment: Sure will check and revert thanks Naveen

Answer (score 0):

selenium tries to use the firefox which is currently installed on your machine. This one is probably newer than the one supported in your selenium version. To fix this you could download a compatible firefox version and pass it in the DesiredCapabilities. It is always helpful to read the [selenium changelog](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG) for the supported firefox versions.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

// linux
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.BINARY, "/path/to/your_firefox/firefox-bin");
// win
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.BINARY, "C:\\path\\to\\your_firefox\\firefox.exe");

WebDriver webdriver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: I am able to run the below sample program succesfully but when i am running my existing selenium scripts system is throwing the error "Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms" but i have configured the selenium 3.0.1 jars and added the system property code and also given the path.,

Answer (score 0):

Just downgrade to firefox 47.0.1 and disable updates. I come accross this issue any time firefox does update to version 50. (issue tested on selenium 2.x and 3.x).

Please take a look [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/browser-support)

Comment: Thanks EL AYADI i will look  in to it

Comment: You re welcome, firefox did it to me again this morning and got the same error...